# In shopify how to display wholesale top link if customer is login in desktop?

Tags: shopify

I want to display "wholesale" collection link on top menu if customer is login otherwise i do not want to display "wholesale" collection link.

I followed following link instruction but it is not working for desktop menu

> https://www.envision.io/blogs/ecommerce-pulse/80312001-how-to-add-a-wholesale-area-to-your-shopify-store-without-an-app

and added bellow code in mobile menu "header.liquid" file

```
{% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu' %}
{% if customer %}
{% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
{% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu-wholesale' %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% for link in linklists[menu_handle].links %}
```

but when i try to put same code for desktop it is not working i am replacing above code with following code

```
{% include 'site-nav', linklist: section.settings.main_linklist %}
```

but it is not working after put following code for desktop nothing display on header before login and after login.

```
{% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu' %}
{% if customer %}
{% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
{% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu-wholesale' %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% for link in linklists[menu_handle].links %}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to replace the whole menu with a wholesale menu or just want to add a single menu item, according to logged in customer tag value?

Comment: I want to replace full menu

Comment: @DHVANITDAVE Which theme you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to try something like this.

```
{% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu' %}
{% if customer %}
   {% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %}
      {% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu-wholesale' %}
   {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% include 'site-nav', linklist: menu_handle %}
```