# How to ad different navigation menus to shopify Debut theme?

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, nav

So I am trying to create different navigation menus for different customer. So when I give a customer a specific tag in shopify (e.g. wholesale) he will see another menu bar than other visitors. Thsi will only happen after he logs into his account.

Now I tried to find the following snippet:
`{% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %}`

to replace it with the following code:

```
{% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu' %}
{% if customer %} 
{% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %} 
{% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu-wholesale' %} 
{% endif %} 
{% endif %} 
{% for link in linklists[menu_handle].links %}
```

But I couldn't find that snippet in the debut code that looks like this:

```
{% comment %}
Renders a list of menu items
Accepts:
- linklist: {Object} Linklist Liquid object (required)
- wrapper_class: {String} CSS wrapper class for the navigation (optional)

Usage:
{% include 'site-nav', linklist: section.settings.main_linklist, wrapper_class: 'site-nav--centered' %}
{% endcomment %}
<ul class="site-nav list--inline{% if wrapper_class != blank %} {{ wrapper_class }}{% endif %}" id="SiteNav">
{% for link in linklists[linklist].links %}
{%- assign child_list_handle = link.title | handleize -%}

{% comment %}
  Check if third-level nav exists on each parent link.
{% endcomment %}
{%- assign three_level_nav = false -%}
{% if link.links != blank %}
  {% if link.levels == 2 %}
    {%- assign three_level_nav = true -%}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}

{% if link.links != blank %}
  <li class="site-nav--has-dropdown{% if three_level_nav %} site-nav--has-centered-dropdown{% endif %}{% if link.active %} site-nav--active{% endif %}" data-has-dropdowns>
    <button class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--main site-nav__link--button{% if link.child_active %} site-nav__link--active{% endif %}" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="SiteNavLabel-{{ child_list_handle }}">
      <span class="site-nav__label">{{ link.title | escape }}</span>{% include 'icon-chevron-down' %}
    </button>

    <div class="site-nav__dropdown{% if three_level_nav %} site-nav__dropdown--centered{% endif %} critical-hidden" id="SiteNavLabel-{{ child_list_handle }}">
      {% if three_level_nav %}
        <div class="site-nav__childlist">
          <ul class="site-nav__childlist-grid">
            {% if link.links != blank %}
              {% for childlink in link.links %}
                <li class="site-nav__childlist-item">
                  <a href="{{ childlink.url }}"
                    class="site-nav__link site-nav__child-link site-nav__child-link--parent"
                    {% if childlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                  >
                    <span class="site-nav__label">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
                  </a>

                  {% if childlink.links != blank %}
                    <ul>
                    {% for grandchildlink in childlink.links %}
                      <li>
                        <a href="{{ grandchildlink.url }}"
                        class="site-nav__link site-nav__child-link"
                        {% if grandchildlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
                      >
                          <span class="site-nav__label">{{ grandchildlink.title | escape }}</span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                  {% endif %}

                </li>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>

      {% else %}
        <ul>
          {% for childlink in link.links %}
            <li>
              <a href="{{ childlink.url }}"
              class="site-nav__link site-nav__child-link{% if forloop.last %} site-nav__link--last{% endif %}"
              {% if childlink.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
            >
                <span class="site-nav__label">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </li>
{% else %}
  <li {% if link.active %} class="site-nav--active"{% endif %}>
    <a href="{{ link.url }}"
      class="site-nav__link site-nav__link--main{% if link.active %} site-nav__link--active{% endif %}"
      {% if link.current %} aria-current="page"{% endif %}
    >
      <span class="site-nav__label">{{ link.title | escape }}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is there another way to add this code snippet into the debut code? How would that code look like?

Every hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to find the code this one `{% include 'site-nav', linklist: section.settings.main_linklist, wrapper_class: 'site-nav--centered' %}`

and after the changes, your code looks like

```
{% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu' %}
{% if customer %} 
  {% if customer.tags contains 'wholesale' %} 
    {% assign menu_handle = 'main-menu-wholesale' %} 
  {% endif %} 
{% endif %} 

{% include 'site-nav', linklist: menu_handle, wrapper_class: 'site-nav--centered' %}
```

**Update:** Here I am changing the menu listing over debut theme latest versions.

1. in the `header.liquid` file I have made an update and add the snippets that check for customer and customer tags if the customer is login and tags contain `wholesale`.
   [image]
2. Register as a new user and from the admin, backend assign tag `wholesale` to the new user account.
   [image]
3. Here is the frontend of the non-login users and log in as a wholesale tagged customer.
   [image]

[image]

Comment: This is a similar question answered in the past also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253679/in-shopify-how-to-display-wholesale-top-link-if-customer-is-login-in-desktop/65286055#65286055

Comment: thanks @Onkar. I replaced the code with the snippet you suggestet. There is no malfuntion but the menu doesn't change once I logged in. Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: are you using the debut theme on the website?

Comment: update the answer, hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time

Comment: glad to know, if you think this works, then please mark this as an answer.